# AngularJS: How to bind properties of an object to scope

Tags: angularjs

I am new to use AngularJS and I am an absolute beginner. I tried using filters. I tried binding to the properties instead of directly binding the object. But the code shows {{x.people}} as the output instead of showing the list. What am I missing out here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>ANGULAR APP</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myFirstController">
    <p>Type a letter in the input field:</p>
    <p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in model.people">
            {{ x.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
var myFirstController = function($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        people: [{
                name: 'Jani',
                country: 'Norway'
            },
            {
                name: 'Carl',
                country: 'Sweden'
            },
            {
                name: 'Margareth',
                country: 'England'
            },
            {
                name: 'Hege',
                country: 'Norway'
            },
            {
                name: 'Joe',
                country: 'Denmark'
            },
            {
                name: 'Gustav',
                country: 'Sweden'
            },
            {
                name: 'Birgit',
                country: 'Denmark'
            },
            {
                name: 'Mary',
                country: 'England'
            },
            {
                name: 'Kai',
                country: 'Norway'
            }
        ];
    };
}

app.controller('myFirstController', myFirstController);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: try to declare your controller like this : app.controller("myFirstController", function($scope){ your code})

Comment: an unexpected token on line 40 ? should I remove the ; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an unnecessary `;` at the end of your json data:

```
$scope.model = {
  people:[
    ...                                   // your data
    {name:'Kai',country:'Norway'}];       // <------ here the ; is illegal
  };          
}
```

refer below fixed example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
var myFirstController = function($scope) {
  $scope.model = {
    people: [{
        name: 'Jani',
        country: 'Norway'
      },
      {
        name: 'Carl',
        country: 'Sweden'
      },
      {
        name: 'Margareth',
        country: 'England'
      },
      {
        name: 'Hege',
        country: 'Norway'
      },
      {
        name: 'Joe',
        country: 'Denmark'
      },
      {
        name: 'Gustav',
        country: 'Sweden'
      },
      {
        name: 'Birgit',
        country: 'Denmark'
      },
      {
        name: 'Mary',
        country: 'England'
      },
      {
        name: 'Kai',
        country: 'Norway'
      }
    ]
  };
}

app.controller('myFirstController', myFirstController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myFirstController">
  <p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in model.people | filter: {name: test}">
      {{ x.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it's actually the ; at the end of {name:'Kai',country:'Norway'}]; that is illegal.

Comment: @JasperZelf thanks for pointing that. I just markered at the wrong place. :P